# OpenQASM circuits in Stim

Tags: qasm, stim

I would like to run circuits saved as OpenQASM circuits in [Stim](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim). Does anyone know how to import these circuits from OpenQASM to Stim?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't directly supported by qiskit or by stim, but you can try using cirq as an intermediary. I don't know how consistently this works, but it works on simple cases.

```
# pip install stimcirq ply

import stimcirq
from cirq.contrib.qasm_import import circuit_from_qasm


cirq_circuit = circuit_from_qasm("""
    OPENQASM 2.0;
    include "qelib1.inc";
    
    qreg q[2];
    creg m[2];
    
    h q[0];
    cx q[0],q[1];
    measure q[0] -> m[0];
    measure q[1] -> m[1];
""")

stim_circuit = stimcirq.cirq_circuit_to_stim_circuit(cirq_circuit)
print(stim_circuit)
```

```
H 0
TICK
CX 0 1
TICK
M 0 1
TICK
```